# How to copy one array1 in another array2 in PLSQL?

Tags: plsql

Let's suppose that I have one little array with 10 rows, and another big array with 50 rows, I want to replace the 10th first rows in the second array with the 10 rows in the little array:

```
declare   
    nb_inactif_gcp number;
    nb_prem_gcp    number;
    type tab_pot is record(
        NUMR_DOSS_ECNM         number,
        ptf    number,
        SEG_BANCO_2020_RELT     varchar(9 BYTE),
        SF     number );
    type tab is table of tab_pot index by binary_integer ;
    tab_sup_pot tab ;
    type inac is record(
        NUMR_DOSS_ECNM         number,
        ptf    number,
        SEG_BANCO_2020_RELT     varchar(9 BYTE),
        SF     number);
    type tablo is table of inac index by binary_integer ;
    tab_inac tablo ;
    TYPE t_tab_emp IS VARRAY  ;
    tab_emp t_tab_emp; 
begin
    -------- initialisation and filling  the table
    for i in 1..nb_prem_gcp loop
            tab_sup_pot(i).NUMR_DOSS_ECNM := i ;
            tab_sup_pot(i).ptf := i;
            tab_sup_pot(i).SEG_BANCO_2020_RELT := 'C';
            tab_sup_pot(i).SF  := i;      
    end loop; 
    for i in 1..nb_prem_gcp loop                            
       select * into tab_sup_pot(i) 
       from (Select * 
             from 
             (Select * 
              from ptf_asup_sans_pro_prem_trie 
              where rownum<=i 
              order by rownum desc) b
         where rownum=1);
     end loop;
     ---initialisation and filling  the table
     for i in 1..nb_inactif_gcp loop
            tab_inac(i).NUMR_DOSS_ECNM := i ;
            tab_inac(i).ptf := i;
            tab_inac(i).SEG_BANCO_2020_RELT := 'C';
            tab_inac(i).SF  := i;      
    end loop; 
    for i in 1..nb_inactif_gcp 
    loop                            
       select * into tab_inac(i) 
       from (Select * 
             from (Select * 
                   from ptf_gcp_inactif
                   where rownum<=i 
                   order by rownum desc
              ) b where rownum=1);
   end loop;
```

My problem is with this part in my code, It doesn't work:

```
   for i in 1..nb_inactif_gcp loop 

  tab_inac(i).NUMR_DOSS_ECNM := tab_sup_pot(i).NUMR_DOSS_ECNM ;
    tab_inac(i).ptf := tab_sup_pot(i).ptf;
    tab_inac(i).SEG_BANCO_2020_RELT := tab_sup_pot(i).SEG_BANCO_2020_RELT ;
    tab_inac(i).SF  :=  tab_sup_pot(i).SF ;
 end loop

end ;
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: By "it doesn't work" what do you mean? You get an error? You don't get any (or the wrong) result? For a start, `tab_inac(i).ptf := tab_sup_pot(i).ptf := i ;` looks wrong; why is that `:= i` there?

Comment: Also `TYPE t_tab_emp IS VARRAY  ;` is incorrect - you're missing both how many elements will be in the varray and the datatype. And your VARCHARs should be VARCHAR2s. And where is `nb_prem_gcp` declared? You can't have run your example code yourself, as it simply doesn't work as it stands. Please update your example code to correct the syntax errors.

Comment: @Boneist I have used i to initialize my arrays.

Comment: You may have done, but you've got two assignments in one line in the last for loop. That's not right.

Comment: @Boneist Could you see please the updated code? my last code doesn't work I mean by that it doesn't give ay error and any resuls too

Comment: `TYPE t_tab_emp IS VARRAY;` is still incorrect - it should be of the form `type <type_name> is VARRAY(<max num of elements>) of <element datatype`, e.g. `TYPE t_varray is VARRAY(100) of varchar2(20)`

Comment: There's a lot of duplication in your programs. Why don't you start by getting a small bit of code working, then grow that?